# SIGABRT error during interface change

Tags: xcode, interface, sigabrt, ios5, xcode4.2

```
(IBAction)switchAppointment {

    AppointmentController *appt = [[AppointmentController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    appt.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:appt animated:YES];

    [appt release];
}
```

That is the code that I use to switch from one .xib to another, however on the line that says "self presentModalViewController:appt animated:YES" , I'm getting a SIGABRT error. My app crashes immediately when I try to go into that interface.

FYI too I'm on Xcode 4.2, but it was doing this before I downloaded the beta.

Comment: 2011-06-12 23:55:32.752 Baseline Vet[197:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <VetViewController: 0x2ba380>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x308d4d2f 0x324ec0e3 0x368000af 0x36800379 0x36713695 0x2e79 0x30842523 0x3669996b 0x36699931 0x3669990d 0x36699663 0x36699d8f 0x3669878f 0x366981e7 0x366705e5 0x3666fe5d 0x31ffe0bb 0x3089f131 0x308a13bf 0x308a1a55 0x3083fc43 0x3083fb05 0x31ffd27b 0x31ffd311 0x3666e127 0x3666b2a5 0x2935 0x28f4)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)

Answer (score 0):

I have also same answer for the code:

```
 nextView *second=[[nextView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];      
[second release];
```

Yours

Miska